# When click on second dropdown black box should remain visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown, nav

In this dropdown nav I'm building if a dropdown is opened and you click to open a second one, the black box should remain visible. At the moment the black box disappears when you click on a second dropdown and reappears after the dropdown is completely opened.

**Update**

I also noticed the black box shows after a dropdown is open and it should open at the same time.

I hope this makes sense and thank you for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = $(this);
    toggleDropDown(menu);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    var container = $("nav .top-bar-section ul");


    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        if ($('a.active').hasClass('active')) {
          $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function toggleDropDown(menu) {
  var isActive = $('a.active').length;
  $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
    if (menu.hasClass('active')) {
      menu.removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      menu.addClass('active');
      menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
      });
    }
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
      $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
    });
  }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

nav {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
    float: left;
}
.top-bar-section a.active {
    background: #f00;
}


.showup {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
li.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.black-bg {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Comment: The `.main-container` element is always visible. The only reason the black background disappears/reappears is because you remove the `black-bg` class, then add it again. If you don't want the background to change, stop messing with that class.

Comment: Sure however I need the black box to close when you click outside the nav or in the same nav button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `black-bg` being added once the menu is clicked, then do not remove and add `black-bg` class on every click event. Simply add it once if the menu have `active` class and remove it when menu do not `active` class. If you remove and add class on every click event then `black-bg` will first disappear and again it will appear. To `black-bg` at the time drop-down is open then remove `$(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");` from callback function of `slideDown()` because a callback function is executed after the current effect is finished.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = $(this);
    toggleDropDown(menu);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    var container = $("nav .top-bar-section ul");


    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        if ($('a.active').hasClass('active')) {
          $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function toggleDropDown(menu) {
  var isActive = $('a.active').length;
  $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
    if (menu.hasClass('active')) {
      menu.removeClass('active');
      $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
    } else {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      menu.addClass('active');
      menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
       });
    }
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
  }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

nav {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
    float: left;
}
.top-bar-section a.active {
    background: #f00;
}


.showup {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
li.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.black-bg {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just move `$(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");` into `if (menu.hasClass('active')) {`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = $(this);
    toggleDropDown(menu);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    var container = $("nav .top-bar-section ul");


    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        if ($('a.active').hasClass('active')) {
          $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function toggleDropDown(menu) {
  var isActive = $('a.active').length;
  $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
    //$(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg"); FROM HERE
    if (menu.hasClass('active')) {
      menu.removeClass('active');
      $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg"); // TO HERE
    } else {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      menu.addClass('active');
      menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
      });
    }
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
      $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
    });
  }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

nav {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #424242;
}

.nav-content {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
}

.top-bar-section {
    float: left;
}
.top-bar-section a.active {
    background: #f00;
}


.showup {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 30px 15px 30px 20px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
li.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
.black-bg {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="top-bar-section">
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 1</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 1.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 2</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 2.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 3</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 3.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="click">Nav item 4</a>
          <div class="showup">
            <div class="nav-content">
              <p>
                Dropdown for Nav Item 4.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="main-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = $(this);
    toggleDropDown(menu);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e) {
    var container = $("nav .top-bar-section ul");


    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").removeClass("black-bg");
        if ($('a.active').hasClass('active')) {
          $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function toggleDropDown(menu) {
  var isActive = $('a.active').length;
  $('a.active').parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
    if (menu.hasClass('active')) {
      menu.removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      menu.addClass('active');
      menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
        $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
      });
    }
  });
  if (!isActive) {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menu.parent().find('.showup').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() {
      $(".main-container").addClass("black-bg");
    });
  }
```

The black box will remain there in this case. What you were previously doing was that you were removing black-box explicitly.